# How to prevent window from closing when modal is opened on keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used keydown event to close the window an its working fine. But when any modal is open, then on Esc key press both modal and window gets closed .

So what I want is:

- On Esc keydown event **if modal is open then it should be closed and then on one more time keydown event it should close window**.

***OR ELSE***

- On Esc keydown event **if modal is not open then it should close Window**.

Till now I have tried this ..

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if ($('#new_party_modal, #edit_party_modal, #delete_party_modal').hasClass('in') != true) {
        switch (e.which) {

            /* Esc Key */
            case 27:
                history.back();
                break;

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: history.back(); should be triggered after closing the model. Write a separate event listener for this .i.e closing of model should invoke another method having history.back()

Comment: I am not too clear what you have to say from your comment @PoojaChauhan , can you explain more ? And what I want is history.back(); should be triggered when Esc is pressed and if any of the modal is not open in window.

Comment: please check the answers section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah finally I got the the way to solve it. What I have done is this:

1. **Disabled the default modal option of keyboard which contains the Esc key event**

   `<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog">`

Here there is two modal options ie. **data-backdrop** and **data-keyboard** that I have turned to false. Turning false to data-keyboard will disable the by default Esc key event of modal to hide.

2. **Manually closing the modal and as per the condition**

`

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 27){
        if($('#myModal').is(':visible')){
            //alert("Modal opened");
            $('#myModal').modal("hide");
        }
        else{
            //alert("Modal not opened");
            history.back();
        }
    }
});
```

Here if modal is open then **is(':visible')** will return true and if not open it will return false. Add the code then.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if($('#new_party_modal, #edit_party_modal, #delete_party_modal').hasClass('in') != true){
        switch(e.which){

            /* Esc Key */
            case 27:
                if(!$('#myModal').hasClass('in')) {
                   history.back();
                }
                break;

        }

    }

});
```

if you have multiple modal in your file then loop through modal class and check for hasClass('in') - if any modal contains 'in' class then don't trigger history.back();

Comment: Its not working. Still it closes both the modal and window. See I have used hasClass('in') once when getting in switch case so do you think I need to use it again in case of esc ?

Comment: I have tried it in your way too .. But no results I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't have this class "in" inside your html/js, then add it dynamically like below.

```
$('#new_party_modal,#edit_party_modal,delete_party_modal').addClass("in");
```

then verify

```
if($('#new_party_modal,#edit_party_modal,delete_party_modal').hasClass('in'))
```

not required to check "true" or "false" explicitly.

then remove this class once you have displayed the respective modal.

```
$('#new_party_modal,#edit_party_modal,delete_party_modal').removeClass("in");
```

Hope, above should work.

Comment: Then debug it, Inspect this element in F12 mode and Verify ur id hold this class or not.

Answer (score 0):

history.back(); should be triggered after closing the model. On press of Esc key close the model.

Write a separate function which is to be called on close event of model and inside that function write "history.back();"

For example if it's a bootstrap model "hidden.bs.modal" event can be used like

```
  $('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
       windowClose();
    });
function windowClose(){
history.back();
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help @pooja ..  
But as you mentioned above when modal will be hidden it will close the window too.  
And bootstrap modal contains Esc key event in its default keyboard options so here the problem was arised that when I press the esc key modal and window both get closed at a time because both modal's and document's Esc key event gets executed at a time and I wanted them to close one by one.  
Here I was in need of the function that could check that modal is open or not so that it can be decided that what to close.  
Anyway I have answered it.

Comment: @KhushalNayani I thought you wanted to do this in a single Esc event just one by one.